# ZK & Spring - Safe to use Executions.getCurrent() in Spring Bean?

Tags: spring, zk

I want to create a utility Bean for common URL parsing in my ZK Composers. However, I want to make sure it is safe to use things like `Executions.getCurrent()` in a Spring managed Bean. I'm pretty sure it is as `Executions.getCurrent()` is static to begin with.

Here's what I'm thinking of doing..

```
@Component
public MyUrlBean {

  // TODO I will, of course, program to an interface here =)

  private static final String MY_OBJECT_URL_PARAMETER = "my_obj";

  public MyObject getMyObjectFromURL() {
    Execution ex = Executions.getCurrent();
    String value = ex.getParameter(MY_OBJECT_URL_PARAMETER)
    // ... db fetch and the like
  }

}
```

..used like so..

```
@VariableResolver(DelegatingVariableResolver.class)
public MyComposer extends SelectorComposer<Window> {

  @WireVariable
  public MyUrlBean myUrlBean;

  @Override
  public void doAfterCompose(Window component) {
    MyObject myObject = myUrlBean.getMyObjectFromURL();
    // ...
  }

}
```

So, doing things this way, should everything work fine or should I anticipate problems with user sessions clashing or the like?

Spring beans are **NOT** static singletons, correct? Instead they are instance classes that are autowired to save computation time of actually newing up objects, correct? If that is the case then there definitely won't be clashes between users like this.

Anyway, as I mentioned, `Executions.getCurrent()` is static. Hmm, how does that work with multiple users accessing a webapp?

Comment: It should work, at least it is supported by ZK officially (refer to official document http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Spring_Essentials/Working_with_ZK_Spring/Working_with_ZK_Spring_Core/Using_Custom_ZK_Scopes_For_Spring_Beans)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, it's safe.**

I don't have much official sources to link here, but for what it's worth, my previous team has been using this in almost every page (to get a user context) of an app serving over 3000 users in production with no recorded problem in two years.